# Python Gmail IMAP After a certain date

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-imap

I am trying to use python IMAP to access my gmail but I want to read only the messages after a certain date. I've narrowed it down to the search portion but I use On and before in the search and it is successful only the after doesn't work. is there a way to retrieve emails after a certain date or will i need to read them all and compare dates?

```
typ, data = conn.search(None, "After 12/12/18")

try:
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                subject=msg['subject']
                by = msg['from']
                to = msg['to']
```

error:

```
imaplib.IMAP4.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone Looking for an answer on this there is a webpage that helped me: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/.

the code to check from a certain date:

```
typ, data = conn.search(None, "SINCE 12-Dec-2018")
```

the month needs to be a Capitalized abbreviation of the month. For Example, Dec for December.